# В чём ошибка скрипта переключаемого меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подскажите, где моя ошибка в коде. Пока не понимаю особо, но старательно учусь.

Требуется создать меню с отображением только лишь одного div'а, есть вот такая, конструкция но скрипт не работает.
К слову сказать кнопка переключения вынесена должна быть в любую точку и вызов скрипта, идёт именно от id кликаемого блока.

Если есть варианты с более изящным решением, то буду благодарен.
Стараюсь изучать язык и понимая писать скрипты сам, потому, прошу особо не пинать за кривоту исполнения задачи.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mf0').css("opacity": "0", "pointer-events": "none");
  $('#mb1').click(function() {
    if ($('#mf0').css("opacity") == "1") {
      $("#mf0").css("opacity": "0", "pointer-events": "none");
    } else if ($('#mf0').css("opacity") == "0") {
      $("#mf0").css("pointer-events": "auto", "opacity": "1");
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#mf0 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 95.5%;
  margin-right: 16%;
  margin-top: 0.75%;
  left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: rgb(180, 192, 204) 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu_bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 10.8em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 86.3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  border: rgb(217, 217, 217) solid 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu_bar_1 {
  margin-top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mf0"></div>
<div class="menu_bar" id="menu_bar_1">
 <p id="txt"><p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",

Несколько свойств за один вызов можно передать в метод `$().css`, используя "javascript object literal" - фигурные скобочки.

```
$('#mf0').css({"opacity": "0", "pointer-events": "none"});
```

Исправьте в трех местах.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @QuisCogitat На здоровье. Успехов!